# rds mysql performance slow under connections

Tags: mysql, performance, database-connection, rds

I have a db.r4.4xlarge (should be able to handle 10000 connections per aws's metrics) mariadb rds instance on aws.  Today we saw a big spike in database connections (around 1000 simultaneous and sustained connections).  We have so many connections because our clients use has use has grown significantly after an acquisition they were a part of.  This instance is supposed to support 10k connections.  CPU and Memory were ok, ie., not pinned an no swapping to my knowledge.  All queries, even simple ones started to take forever.  Even stuff like

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE if not exists TTT0dfa3c18b1036a73dd5d5581bddac484_2 LIKE TTT0dfa3c18b1036a73dd5d5581bddac484;

was taking > 5 seconds... and that's not even loading any table data, just the structure.  I'm trying to get to the root of the issue and find a solution.  Can anyone point me in a direction that may lead to a better understanding of what was going on.  The crux of my confusion is that the cpu and memory looked ok while all this was happening, just the connections stood out as unusually high.  Should I try using ec2 with ssd, etc, any ideas/thoughts would be helpful as I am not experienced with this type of issue.

below I've added a couple pics of the only metrics that stood out at all.   connections and binlogusage and freeable memory.  IO/cpu was good.

[image: freeable memory]
[image: db connections]

[image: binlogusage]

Comment: With that many active connections, you probably are seeing contention between the workloads on the various connections. MySQL won't pin memory, it will just make connections wait. Please [edit] your question to give more information about why you have so many connections.

Comment: ok, edited the original question.  Thanks O. Jones

Comment: if connections wait will it show the query as running so slow or will it just wait and then the query should run in 'normal' time because the query (any query) was not running in normal time.

Comment: One query grabbed locks on several things; another connection was stalled; etc.  Eventually, so many connections were waiting for resources that everyone was bottled up.  Find the slow queries (see if you can get the slowlog from RDS).  Let's try to speed up the one(s) that _started_ this thundering herd.

Comment: If you can, please provide the values indicated here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning .  The first I want to see is `Max_used_connections`.  `max_connections = 10000` is not a problem _if_ nearly all are in `Sleep` status.  RDS _should not_ let you swap, but the high disk usage makes me wonder.  (Swapping is _terrible_ for MySQL performance.)

Comment: Rick, there ended up being several layers of sql inefficiency but in the end we found one query that was locking a table that was used heavily by hundreds of queries a second.  You are right, issue resolved.  Thank you.